# Vb.net - Selected Row Crystal reports

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

This is my first time using Crystal reports.

I have a Datagrid which i populate with this:

```
Public Sub DisplayRecords()
     Try
        Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from workshoptbl order by ID desc", strDatabaseCon)
        dsetAssets = New DataSet
        da.Fill(dsetAssets, "workshoptbl")
        workshopdgvdata.DataSource = dsetAssets.Tables("workshoptbl").DefaultView
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I then have a report button which creates a report. This report includes all rows from my Workshoptbl.

```
Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    cryRpt.Load("\CrystalReport2.rpt")
    WorkshopCRP.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    WorkshopCRP.Refresh()
    WorkshopCRP.Show()
```

What i am trying to do is when i highlight a row and click report/print, that only the highlighted row gets sent to the report viewer page.

My Datasource for CrystalReport2 is configured in Database expert on the report page.

If someone could point me in the right direction i'd greatly appreciate it.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter in the CR file, associate it with the id of the row and then modify your Report/Print code to pass the id of the selected row to the report like this :

```
WorkshopCRP.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
WorkshopCRP.SetParameterValue("LineNo", workshopdgvdata.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value)
WorkshopCRP.Refresh()
```

In the example above, the parameter is named "LineNo" and the row's id (in the database table) is in the first cell of the row (in the datagridview).

Comment: Hi @Disman38 i've added the parameter with a dynamic value is this correct?

Comment: @Matt A Static value should be enough. The important part is to associate the parameter field with the id of the row using the "Select Expert".